# SendKeys in firefox quantum using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys, geckodriver, firefox-quantum

I have been trying to press (CTRL + ALT + 'f') after selecting a WebElement using selenium 3.5 on firefox quantum. This is the code I have written :

```
WebElement ele = m_driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tm-project-name"));
ele.click();
Actions act = new Actions(m_driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
act.sendKeys(Keys.ALT).perform();
act.sendKeys("f").perform();
```

For performing this work I also tried this method

```
act.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ALT, "F")).build().perform();
```

Both of these methods works fine on chrome browser but fails to work in firefox quantum.
Can anyone help me out on this issue.

Comment: For what purpose are you trying to pass control+Alt+"f"?

Comment: Instead of the whole `Actions act ... act.sendKeys("f").perform();` part, try to add after the click: `ele.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ALT, "F"));`

Comment: @Pradeephebbar I need to execute this in my application and highlight an element.

Comment: @GalAbra I tried this also but this is not working in firefox quantum.

Comment: What happens with the `Java` **`click()`**? Do you see any error? Update the error stack trace within the Question. Also update the purpose of `press (CTRL + ALT + 'f')`.

Comment: @DebanjanB I need to click on a web element that can be done by simply clicking on the locator value but in firefox quantum its not working. Beside that clicking can be done using (CTRL + ALT + 'f') so I am trying to perform that. No error in Java **click()**. It does not stuck at that point and moves to the next line.

Comment: See, Java `click()` is quite proven and powerful. If it fails there would be some reasons. With out proper probe with `click()` and any valid reason it won't be a good idea to shift focus to other `click()`. Add a listener and try to see if you can catch up with whats wrong happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass control+Alt+"f" using `Robot class` , this will work in all browsers.

Try the below code.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Here are the needed imports... for anyone trying :   1) import java.awt.Robot; 2) 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement ele = m_driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tm-project-name"));
ele.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT+Keys.CONTROL+'f');
```

I normally write in python, and I checked it in my IDE before I submitted...Python works... thinking this is the C# version